# Will traffic exchange programs work in pay per impression ad campaigns?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, traffic

I'm having a technology blog with nearly 3000 visitors a day (1000 - 1300 unique visitors). I'm generating visitors through traffic exchange programs like `hitleap.com`, `addmefast.com`.

Now I'm planning to go with some pay per impression programs. So far I came to know that Google AdSense won't allow using traffic exchange programs.

Did all pay-per-impression programs will follow the same? Will I get banned using traffic exchange programs?

Comment: Google Adsense Blog: [A note on traffic exchange programs](http://adsense.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/note-on-traffic-exchange-programs.html)

Comment: Most definitely will because the traffic is typically very poor quality.

Comment: If it's bot hitting your site it'll be 100% bounce rate and less than 1 minute on the page. Google knows this and will ban you. When you say you have 3000 visitors nearly 1000-1300 unique what you really mean is you have a lot of fake visitors maybe even programs. I wonder what the OS, broswer, resolution, IP, and Hosts are of all your visitors. How unique are they really? And do you think Google might already know of some of these IPs? What a waste of money, I really hope you are not showing these stats to people and getting them to pay for advertising when you're cheating them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you risk losing your AdSense account. Once you start displaying Google ads on your website/blog, you have implicitly agreed to their policy.

From AdSense's program policy:

> To ensure a positive experience for Internet users and Google advertisers, sites displaying Google ads may not:
>   Use third-party services that generate clicks or impressions such as paid-to-click, paid-to-surf, autosurf and click-exchange programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only receive small amounts of Traffic then some key elements on your site is obviously a problem.

Rather than spending money on Purchasing Traffic you should first address why you are only receiving 3,000 visits. It is possible to get lots of traffic without engaging in traffic buying Schemes.

**SEO**

Ensure that your SEO is good but not over done. Your pages should generally have 400+ Uniquely written text (NO COPY AND PASTE) be fun to read and contain plenty of images as well as good page description, title and headers.

**Adwords**

Rather than buying traffic based on Impressions it's generally best to use paid traffic based on Clicks as you will find that people who link generally want to see the content behind the add while impressions is simply giving them a chance to click.

**MORE.... Content**

The best way to improve visitors is to write awesome content, I know so many people don't believe this but the more pages with quality content you have then the more people that can find you and the natural link building occurs. With few pages or thin pages your reducing your chances.

**Buy Content**

If your willing to depart your cash on getting people to your site you should look into getting blogs and professional content writers to provide you with articles that can increase your rankings. I consider this by far one of the most affordable and effective routes. Just ensure they are not providing you with spun content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get banned by Google if they find out. If you are lucky you get a warning and they disable ads, but they can also disable your whole account. If you want to use Google AdSense, you have to live to their policies 100%.

You can use chitika or adbrite, their policies are much looser than Google.